# <CLOSED(Reason: JSON String Error)>Unable to Deserialize List<myObject> from Valid JSON

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am trying to de-serialize a JSON string to a List of objects. The json string is a valid json as verified from http://jsonlint.com/

This is the string

```
[
{
    "Employee_OID": 18450,
    "First_Name": "ABDUL",
    "Last_Name": "RAJPUT"
},
{
    "Employee_OID": 22446,
    "First_Name": "ABDUL",
    "Last_Name": "KHAN"
}
]
```

Previously I was successfully deserializing individual objects by the below code

```
Employee emp = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<Employee>(hdfEmployees.Value);
```

but now when I am trying to deserialize a List of objects by the same code

```
List<Employee> emp = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<List<Employee>>(hdfEmployees.Value);
```

it gives me below error

```
Invalid JSON primitive: <my json string>
```

I have also tried IList and Employee[] in place of List (as suggested by an answer on another question) but no use.

Comment: Have you tried IEnumerable?

Comment: nopes, still giving the same error

Comment: are you sure Employee_OID is an int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Employee_OID { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"[{""Employee_OID"": 18450,""First_Name"": ""ABDUL"",""Last_Name"": ""RAJPUT""},{""Employee_OID"": 22446,""First_Name"": ""ABDUL"",""Last_Name"": ""KHAN""}]";
        List<Employee> emp = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<List<Employee>>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(emp.First().First_Name);
    }
}
```

So check your input

Comment: I got the problem, actually I am trying to Deserialize a list of above 1000 employees. It works fine for 3-4 employees.

Comment: Give a link to your text file with input json - i'll try

Comment: can i send you the file anywhere else?

Comment: i just checked my json, actually i fetched the elements from service in a chunk of 20 objects(get request size limitation), and then I appended json to the field, i guess thats where i did it wrong, after each 20 objects, there is a ][ in the string. Let me try it omitting these, then i will send you the file.

Comment: Yes, i guess error in your input - i've just successfuly deserialized 1456 elements - check your json one again - i'm sure it has an error. Try to past it at pastbin or somewhere else - i'll investigate it

Comment: I AM REALLY SORRY, MY BAD. Actually I was appending the json strings of the objects fetched in chunks. Resulting in many json strings appended in one.

Comment: How can i close this question? someone else might get confused.

Comment: Look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/how-to-close-a-question-in-stackoverflow-com

Answer (score 2):

Your error is not connected to `JavaScriptSerializer`. I've just tested following code:

```
string input = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, File.ReadAllLines("Input.txt"));
List<Employee> emp = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<List<Employee>>(input);
```

where `Input.txt` contains your sample input and it works just fine = `emp` is a list with 2 `Employee` objects.

`Employee` class is defined as

```
public class Employee
{

    public int Employee_OID { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
}
```

You have to check your input string if it really matches your question sample data.

Comment: I got the problem, actually I am trying to Deserialize a list of above 1000 employees. It works fine for 3-4 employees.

Comment: Number of elements doesn't matter as long as they are all valid.